# How can we use Azure data factory to ingest files from sharepoint to the data lake

Tags: azure-data-factory

We have a requirement wherein we need to use Azure Data Factory to move the files in sharepoint to the ADLS.

How can we do this ?

Thanks

Comment: Start by googling. Then you might find this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#copy-file-from-sharepoint-online. Try it and come with any specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

ADF supports REST API as a source. Sharepoint has a REST API that helps to copy files and you can use sink as ADLS.

Below link provides all details :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/data-factory/connector-sharepoint-online-list?tabs=data-factory#copy-file-from-sharepoint-online